# Windows 8 gaming performance compared to Windows 7

Tags: windows-8, gaming

I have seen several people who switched to 8 from 7 say that they have experienced a 10-15% boost in FPS and performance across several modern games including Skyrim.

Have any benchmarks been done that show if this is true? Does this sound likely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-8-gaming-performance,3331-13.html

> Of the 10 games we benchmarked, only one demonstrated a significant difference in moving from Windows 7 to Windows 8, and only on Nvidia's GeForce GTX 660. That game was Borderlands 2, where our average measured frame rate dropped from 86.6 to 81 FPS. But at that speed, the five-frame drop is hardly worth fretting over.

Comment: As long as I don't suffer performance degradation, I'm not too bothered.